# $(p \land q)\implies(p \lor q)$, how to make a truth table with $p$ twice?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I thought I understood truth tables, until I saw repeats of $p$.  I guessed on this one: $p \implies \neg p$.  This is what I have:

$$ 
\begin{array}{c||c||c}
p & \neg p & p \implies \neg p\\
\hline
T & F & T\\
\hline
F & T & T
\end{array} 
$$

Now I am trying to write the truth table of  $(p \land q)\implies(p \lor q)$.  Can someone help me?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). I tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: Break it up: First the two usual columns: $p$, $q$. Then build the $p \land q$, and the $p \lor q$ columns from the values in the first two columns. Then build the final column based on columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Break your formula into smaller parts. In your example evaluate first $(p \land q)$ and $(p \lor q)$. Since you have two variables, the truth table has $2^2=4$ entries, on for each variable assignment. Filling out the table is now easy, proceed column by column.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
p & q & (p\land q) & (p\lor q) & (p\land q) \implies (p\lor q) \\
F & F & F& F& T \\
F & T &  F & T& T\\
T & F & F&T& T\\
T & T & T &T& T\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 4):

Well the first thing to do is to simplify the expression.

$(p \wedge q) \rightarrow (p \vee q)$

By material implication

$\neg (p \wedge q) \vee (p \vee q)$

By De Morgan's law

$(\neg p) \vee (\neg q) \vee (p \vee q)$

By associativity

$((\neg p) \vee p) \vee ((\neg q) \vee q)$

Which is always true because $((\neg p) \vee p)$ is always true and $((\neg q) \vee q)$ is also always true.

So the logic table contains all T regardless of what p and q are assigned to.

Alternatively, you can painfully substitute, which I will start here:

$p = T$, $q = T$ gives:

$(T \wedge T) \rightarrow (T \vee T)$

$(T \wedge T) = T$, $(T \vee T) = T$, and $T \rightarrow T = T$

so this case is T.

You can do likewise for the other 3 cases.

Answer (score 3):

When building the truth table for a formula, across each row you use the same truth values for the sentence variables that are used.  Think of this like evaluating a polynomial at a specific number.  If $$f(x) = 3x^2 - 5x + 6,$$ then to evaluate $f(2)$ we replace *each instance* of $x$ in the expression above by $2$, and then calculate as usual: $$f(2) = 3 \cdot 2^2 - 5 \cdot 2 + 6 = 12 - 10 + 6 = 8.$$

We do the same for each row of a truth table.  So let's evaluate some rows of the truth table of the formula you are interested in:
$$
\begin{array}{cc||l}
p & q & ( p \wedge q ) \Rightarrow ( p \vee q ) \\
\hline
T & F & ( T \wedge F ) \Rightarrow ( T \vee F ) = F \Rightarrow T = T \\
F & F & ( F \wedge F ) \Rightarrow ( F \vee F ) = F \Rightarrow F = T
\end{array}
$$