# Show that (p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q) is a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am having a little trouble understanding proofs without truth tables particularly when it comes to →

Here is a problem I am confused with:

Show that (p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q) is a tautology

The first step shows: (p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q) ≡ ¬(p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∨ q)

I've been reading my text book and looking at Equivalence Laws. I know the answer to this but I don't understand the first step.

How is (p ∧ q)→ ≡ ¬(p ∧ q)?

If someone could explain this I would be extremely grateful. I'm sure its something simple and I am overlooking it.

The first thing I want to do when seeing this is
(p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q) ≡ ¬(p → ¬q)→(p ∨ q)

but the answer shows:
¬ (p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∨ q)     (by logical equivalence)

I don't see a equivalence law that explains this.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me, the negation of the conclusion is $\neg p \wedge \neg q$ which clearly falsifies the hypothesis.

Comment: Another question about the same formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275689/p-land-q-impliesp-lor-q-how-to-make-a-truth-table-with-p-twice

Comment: What does "T.T." in the middle of your question mean?

Comment: @TRiG - I'm pretty sure it's just a tearful face emoticon.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is because of the following equivalence law, which you can prove from a truth table:
$$r\rightarrow s\equiv \lnot r\lor s.$$
If you let $r = p\land q$ and $s = p\lor q$, you get what you are looking for, namely that
$$(p\land q)\rightarrow (p\lor q)\equiv \lnot(p\land q)\lor(p\lor q).$$

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware you could do it like that.

Answer (score 19):

This is a classic equivalence
$$p\to q \equiv \neg p\lor q.\tag 1$$

We can examine equivalence using a truth table
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
p&q&\neg p&p\to q&\neg p\lor q\\\hline
T&T&F&T&T\\\hline
T&F&F&F&F\\\hline
F&T&T&T&T\\\hline
F&F&T&T&T
\end{array}

Hence, $p\to q\equiv \neg p\lor q$.

Further, if $a \equiv p\land q$ and $b\equiv p\lor q$, and so
$$a\to b\equiv \neg a\lor b\equiv \neg(p\land q)\lor(p\lor q)\equiv (\neg p\lor \neg q)\lor (p\lor q),$$
by using $(1)$.

Answer (score 7):

To show
 (p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q).

If (p ∧ q) is true,
then both p and q
are true,
so (p ∨ q) is true,
and $T \to T$
is true.

If (p ∧ q) is false,
then
(p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q)
is true,
because false implies anything.

Q.E.D.

Comment: True, but doesn't address what seems to be the main question.

Answer (score 6):

I know you asked specifically about a given proof, but here is another way:

(1) Assume p ∧ q

(2) By ∧-elimination, p

(3) By ∨-introduction, p ∨ q

(4) By →-introduction and marking the assumption (1), (p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q).

In less formal language: *if* P and Q is true, then you can look at either P or Q separately and it must be true. Now from any true statement you can create a longer true statement by creating a disjunction with any statement: if P is true, then "P or R" is also true for *any* statement R (e.g. if you are sure "it is raining", then it is also the case that "it is raining or you are a dragon"). In particular taking R = Q in this case allows you to reason that P or Q is true.

Answer (score 6):

Combine your first step with [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

$$ \begin{array}{rcll}
(p ∧ q) → (p ∨ q) & ≡ & ¬(p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∨ q) & \text{Definition of $→$} \\
& ≡ & (¬p ∨ ¬q) ∨ (p ∨ q) & \text{De Morgan's Law}\\
& ≡ & (¬p ∨ p) ∨ (¬q ∨ q) & \text{Associativity and commutativity of $∨$} \\
& ≡ & T ∨ T  \\
& ≡ & T\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Alternately:

```
 p ∧ q        Assumed           <--------\
 p            base Extract P ∧ Q ⊢ P     |
 p ∨ q        base Widening P ⊢ P ∨ Q    |
 (p∧q)→(p∨q)  pop assumption            -/
```

This isn't quite rendering right -- need a fixed width font.

Answer (score 2):

As $\lnot p\lor p$ is trivial and $p→q$ means $p$ necessitates $q$. This gives $\lnot p\lor q$.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an inference rule approach to showing that $P \to Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q$, using the [Constructive Dillema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dilemma) inference rule:

$$ \large \frac{P \to Q,~ R \to S, ~P \lor R}{ Q \lor S}$$

It can be shown that $\neg P \lor  P$ and $\neg P \to \neg P$ are tautologies, and given that we know $ P \to Q $ , we can substitute into the above inference rule.

$$  \large \frac{ \neg P \to \neg P,~P \to Q,~ ~\neg P \lor P}{  \neg P \lor Q }$$

So far we have shown that $ (P \to Q) ~\vdash  (\neg P \lor Q)$. To finish proving the equivalency $ P \to Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q ~$ we also need to show $  (\neg P \lor Q)  \vdash  (\neg P \lor Q)     $. I don't see an obvious inference rule at this point, but we could show it by contradiction.