# What is the logical implication here?

Tags: logic

Is there a difference between ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ $C$, and, ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ ($C$ and $A$)? Or if I swapped $A$ in the last statement with $B$? (Edit)
If we know that ($A$ & $B$) $\rightarrow$ $C$, then to prove the $\iff$ case we can just show that $C$ $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$). All good here, however I have just learnt from this post that ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ $C$ is equivalent to ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ ($C$ and $A$), so showing $C$ $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$) should be the same as as showing ($C$ and $A$) $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$), but these two statements are not equivalent. Where is my mistake?
Thanks.
The reason why I am asking is that when I tried to prove the $\iff$ case in a logical statement I got two contradictory answers, as $C$ $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$) and ($C$ and $A$) $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$) should be two ways of showing the same thing but they are obviously not.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $x+3=9$ then $x\neq x^2-2x$.

Comment: I will make an edit.

Comment: And just logically, the statements "$(A \,\& \,B)\implies C$" and $(A\, \& \,B)\implies (C\,\&\, B)$ are equivalent (there is nothing gained by writing, in essence, $B\implies B$).

Comment: Lulu this was what I needed to hear, thanks!

Comment: So does $(A &B) \rightarrow C$ and $(A &B) \righarrow (C &A)$ also mean same thing?

Comment: Post edit, your various assumptions still don't make sense.  Writing $(x+4)^2=(x+4)^2$ adds nothing (of course $A=A$).  It's not clear what you are trying to get at here...I suggest you avoid algebraic statements, as your use of them just leads to confusion.  You can just refer to abstract premises $A,B,C, \cdots$ as needed.

Comment: Yes.  Again, the logical implication $A\implies A$ is always true.

Comment: I do not quite get how by adding $A$ or $B$ its the same as $B \rightarrow B$?

Comment: If $A\implies C$ and $A\implies A$ (always true) then $A$ implies both $A$ and $C$.  That's all that says.

Comment: One last question, does that mean $(A & B)$ $\rightarrow$ $A$?

Comment: Yes, that implication is true.

Comment: Thanks for your help lulu, even if what I was asking may have been obvious.

Comment: I have no idea what is meant in the question. There is a reason we use parentheses...

Comment: Edited to add brackets. Sorry.

Comment: As I already said, asking a separate question about bunch of different propositions won't get you far without having basic understanding of truth tables. It's ok to make mistakes, we all learn from that, but that should inspire you to learn correct way to approach these questions. I gave you one link with an example how to make a truth table for compound proposition and it doesn't take lot of effort to find many similar questions on MSE. If you prefer to learn from videos, "how to build truth tables" returned many results on YouTube. Go through that and then return to what's troubling you now.

Comment: Its not the building the truth table that is the issue, but rather I am asking a conceptual question, can you not swap two equivalent logical statements?

Comment: @NavBhatthal yes it is the issue because you don't know how to verify if two logical statements are equivalent or not.

Comment: Alright I will go learn how to make a truth table properly, but still my question holds if you have shown me two statements to be equivalent (in your answer) why can I not swap them as and when if they are the same.

Comment: $(A\&B)\to C$ is equivalent to $(A\& B)\to (A\& C)$, but $C\to (A\&B)$ is not equivalent to $(C\&A)\to(A\& B)$. You can't switch the order in implication and expect nothing to change, implication is not symmetric. Correct way to apply what you learned from the first equivalence is to conclude that $(C\& A)\to (A\& B)$ is equivalent to $(C\& A) \to B$, quite different than $C\to (A\to B)$. Intuitively, it's much easier to prove $B$ from assumptions $C$ and $A$ than it is to prove both $A$ and $B$ from the single assumption $C$.

Comment: Alright. So if I have ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ $C$ to show the $\iff$ case I have to show $C$ $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$). And if I have ($A$ and $B$) $\rightarrow$ ($C$ and $A$), to show the $\iff$ case I must show that ($C$ and $A$) $\rightarrow$ ($A$ and $B$). Which is not the same as the first case, can you explain intuitively as to why you must show two different statements to be true to prove the same thing? (Or are ($A$ and $B$) $\iff$ ($C$) , and  ($A$ and $B$) $\iff$ ($C$ and $A$) completely different?)

Comment: But you are not proving the same thing. $(A\&B) \leftrightarrow C$ is not equivalent to $(A\& B)\leftrightarrow(A\& C)$.

Comment: So by swapping an equivalent statement for an equivalent statement we have changed the logic? (Perhaps I am thinking of this too much like regular equations etc, and logic has some sort of "direction?)

Comment: What equivalent statements have you swapped? You swapped $C$ and $C\& A$. They are not equivalent. In the first case it turned out to work, in the second it doesn't. Because they are not equivalent.

Comment: Yeah so is there a reason as to why it works in one direction and not the other? Or is it just a case of sometimes.

Comment: It works in one direction because if you assume $A$ and $B$, you can trivially conclude $A$, so proving $C$ from those assumptions is as hard as proving $C\&A$ or $C\& A\&B$. The whole difficulty lies in proving $C$ and $A$ and $B$ come for free since we assumed them to be true. It's much different if you change assumptions. The more assumptions you have, easier it becomes to prove something. So, proving $A\&B$ from $C$ is much harder than proving $A\& B$ from $A\& C$, because if you add $A$ as assumption, half of the statement $A\& B$ is already proven trivially.

Comment: Ennar I cannot thank you enough. Something just clicked, may I commend you for sticking with me (a silly idiot) the whole way through. This is the beauty of stackexchange. +1

Comment: You are welcome, but please try to spend more time to write a question. It's not good that most of the information of what is actually troubling you we learn by exchanging lots of comments. MSE is not a forum, all this information you shared later should have been included in the original question. You would get more detailed answers and your question wouldn't be closed. Also, I still hope you'll learn truth tables properly, it's like taking step from learning multiplication table to learning to calculate $2\cdot 3 + 3\cdot (1 + 2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $A$, $B$ and $C$ are logical statements, then $A \wedge B\Rightarrow C$ is logically equivalent to $\neg (A\wedge B)\vee C$ (it is actually defined that way. In generall you have $A\Rightarrow B \overset{\text{def}}{\Leftrightarrow} \neg A\vee B$). Hence by De Morgans law you have

$A\wedge B\Rightarrow C$  $\Leftrightarrow$ $\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C$

$A\wedge B\Rightarrow C \wedge B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C\wedge B$

Looking at the tables:

[image]

[image]

You can conclude that both statements are logically equivalent. So it doesn't matter. You can write it in both ways.

And you can also swap $A$ and $B$ in the last statement. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Are $A \rightarrow B$ and ($A$ & $B$) $\rightarrow$ $B$ logically equivalent?

Comment: @NavBhatthal you can make truth tables like the answer shows you to do. Surely you don't intend to keep asking about every single proposition that comes to your mind?

Comment: I am stuck when I make the truth table which has the same statement on both sides. I can do the table for $A \rightarrow B$.

Comment: @NavBhatthal, make a table for $A\&B$ and copy $B$ then make a table for $(A\&B)\to B$ the same way you would for $C\to B$ but you copy truth values for $C$ from $A\& B$.

Comment: I know that $A & B$ $\rightarrow$ $C$ says that  when $A$ and $B$ are both true, $C$ is true, but how do I know that this is the same as saying that $A \rightarrow B$? (The truth table method is confusing me because there is no $B$ on the left hand side of the second statement so I dont know what to compare)

Comment: @NavBhatthal let's say that the truth value of $A$ is $0$ and of $B$ is $1$. Then, the truth value of $(A\&B)\to B$ is $(0\&1)\to 1$. Can you resolve that?

Comment: I am very confused, I will look more into logic then come back with the correct answer, but I suspect that they are the same.

Comment: @NavBhatthal they are not. Focus on learning how to make truth tables. For example, you can look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/275706/122131).

Comment: Can you see my edit please? Thanks.